Analogs of Plücker relations in Clifford algebras, and Bott periodicity (?)
Classical Plücker relations can be viewed as conditions on coefficients of an element $x=\sum_Sc_Se_S$, $S=(i_1,...,i_k)$, $i_1<\cdots<i_k$, $\{i_1,...,i_k\}\subset\{1,...,n\}$ of an exterior power $\bigwedge^k(V)$ of an $n$-dimensional vector space that are necessary and sufficient for $x$ to be of the form $v_1\land\cdots\land v_k$ for some $v_1,...,v_k\in V$. Assigning to the subspace spanned by $v_1,...,v_k$ the line through $v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k$ determines the Plücker embedding of the Grassmannian $\operatorname{Gr}(k,V)$ into the projective space $\operatorname{\mathbb P}(\bigwedge^k(V))$, and the Plücker relations describe the image of this embedding.
In the Clifford algebra $\operatorname{Cl}(V,q)$ with respect to a quadratic form $q$, elements of the form $v_1\cdots v_k$ are of importance for the construction of various groups like $\Gamma_q$, $\operatorname{Pin}(q)$ and $\operatorname{Spin}(q)$: these groups consist of elements as above.
As an aside, if $q$ admits nonzero isotropic elements then not all nonzero $v\in V$ are invertible in $\operatorname{Cl}(q)$ and all possible products $v_1\cdots v_k$ form a semigroup rather than group.
A basis $e_1,...,e_n$ of $V$ determines a basis $(e_S)_{S\subseteq\{1,...,n\}}$ of $\operatorname{Cl}(V,q)$ as above. Are there relations on coefficients of an $x\in\operatorname{Cl}(V,q)$ in this basis which, similarly to Plücker relations, would give necessary and sufficient conditions for $x$ to be of the form $v_1\cdots v_k$?
Is there an analog of the Plücker embedding for this case? This would be interesting as it would provide a common environment for coexistence of Grassmannians and Spin groups, somehow hinting at Bott periodicity.

Since the Clifford algebra and the exterior algebra are isomorphic as vector spaces, I would expect that the answer is "yes".
